# COUNTIF/COUNTA with Dynamic Range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Right now I am manually adding ranges to the formula I would like to see if it is possible to add into the formula to automatically extend to the last cell without manual input

Column range
=COUNTIF(D5:D273, "TRUE")/COUNTA(D5:D273)

Row range
=COUNTIF(D5:AM5, "TRUE")/COUNTA(D5:AM5)

Current formula counts all cells in range for "True" Statement compared to all cells within range with any data and makes a percentile of that data to see what the average of passing score is.

I have googled and found OFFSET statements as well as INDEX statement and neither seem to work for what I need these formulas to perform

Having the formula automatically map out to the end of the range will be extremely time saving as I would only need to copy and past and then drag auto fill down the ranges without manually grabbing the end of the row or column.

The values are all text with a "TRUE" or "FALSE"

[image: Sample]

I have attached a very small sample size, of what it looks like

row 3 started from column E is where formula starts for columns

column D starting in row 3 is where formula starts for rows

The shown picture is how the data is delivered from our script, but instead of 6 machines its 15,000 and instead of 3 tests it is 400.

Comment: And you are sure they are not booleans? `TRUE` is not the same as `"TRUE"` If TRUE is in D5 and you put this formula `=TYPE(D5)` into an unused cell, do you get 2 or 4 as a result?

Comment: Those are almost positively real booleans, not text. Unless you changed the cell alignment, only booleans and errors default to center alignment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a blank cell on the right and bottom border, you can create a range that goes up to the blanks by using `MATCH` and `OFFSET` (or `INDEX`).

Here's an example.  The `MATCH` function searches everything to the right for the first blank and returns and index of 5.  `OFFSET` returns the last non-blank cell.  Then the `B7:OFFSET...` complete the range.

The columns averages are very similar except offset by rows instead of columns in the `OFFSET` function.  E.g. for B2:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:OFFSET(B3,MATCH(TRUE,(B3:B1048576)=(""),0)-2,0), TRUE)/COUNTA(B3:OFFSET(B3,MATCH(TRUE,(B3:B1048576)=(""),0)-2,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is make the ranges really big for the formulas that are calculating the percentages.

For example, the formula for the average score would be

```
=COUNTIF(E3:XFD1048576, TRUE)/COUNTA(E3:XFD1048576)
```

So any time you add a row or column to your spreadsheet, it'll be picked up by this formula.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for me after reading about INDEX, or OFFSET, was to use specific columns only to data (no SUM  or anything at the bottom) and then just make use of the formulae with full range, e.g. SUMIF(A:A,B:B,">0"). Maybe this could he useful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).